# Looking for good functional / oop / meta programming language with :

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming

I want it will be

- native code generation // Able to compile with something like GHC
- cross-platform (win / linux)
- Functional and a bit object-oriented
- lambdas, pattern matching, tuples and other functional stuff
- Great metaprogramming support
- Indent and minimum borders
- static typing
- also I want [Mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) support :)
- possibility to build web sites based on some frameworks is also good plus.
- so and yes, performance and stability matters.

I started **Haskell**, but still being not sure about it, because there is OCaml. And I've got F# experience. But as far as I know **OCalm** is a bit OOP and sometimes even faster (not sure about it) I never tried it. There is also erlang, I know nothing about **erlang**. And maybe I'm missing something more..? **Python**, I have no idea about python here, it's functional and it's oop and it supports mixin and popular and fast, but I don'r really think that python is able for all the functional magic, I think it can not.

I know that this thread/topic is a like a talking about nothing or like a language war, but I seriously and really want to hear your vision of it.

Comment: I think requiring native code generation greatly limits the options. I think [nemerle](http://nemerle.org/About/) is worth a shot.

Comment: @back2dos ye, I like Nemerle, but using it with mono for small utils or web is a bit ODD job. I think so. And indent still got bad support. I'm using Nemerle, but sometimes. For now I'm using it lesser then F#.

Comment: Looks like you want C++ with a (runtime) functional paradigm (it already have compile-time functional paradigm).

Comment: @Klaim I really don't want C++. generation native code with ghc -> gcc is OK for me.

Comment: A language with all of those requirements? Probably one you write yourself.

Comment: @Rein Henrichs but I want to chose one even if there is no perfect one with those requirements. The only thing is I'm still thinking if my chosen (Haskell) is exactly what I wanted to get, because there is other languages I completely have no idea about.

Comment: Ruby is OK for metaprogramming/DSL and also has mixins/first order functions etc.

Comment: @arctic_dev: but no static typing, no native code generation (could do bytecode with JRuby...), and performance is not sooo great at all (but OP just said it "matters", we don't know to which extent).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Clojure** seems a pretty good fit for all your requirements.

- native code generation / Able to
  compile with something like GHC - *Yes (all Clojure code gets compiled to Java bytecode which subsequently gets compiled to native code via JIT on the JVM)*
- cross-platform (win / linux) - *Yes - anywhere the JVM runs*
- Functional and a bit object-oriented - *Yes - Clojure is a functional language first and foremost, but also has OO support if you want it (via either Java interoperability or CL-style objects). Having said that, OO is generally considered unidiomatic in Clojure.*
- lambdas, pattern matching, tuples and
  other functional stuff - *Yes - it's a fairly standard functional language in this regard. The auther (Rich Hickey) was somewhat inspired by Haskell.*
- Great metaprogramming support - *Yes - "code-is-data" applies as with all Lisps and you get great macro functionality*
- Indent and minimum borders - *Yes though surely that's actually an editor rather than a language feature??*
- static typing - *Yes - Clojure is dynamic by default but you can provide static or primitive type hints whenever you like for a performance boost*
- also I want Mixin support :) - *Yes - can be achieved in various ways (e.g. macros) though you'll probably not want or need it after you've discovered Clojure's protocol functionality....*
- possibility to
  build web sites based on some
  frameworks is also good plus. - *Yes - there are frameworks like Ring/Compojure in Clojure and you can also use any Java frameworks*
- so and yes, performance and stability matters. - *Yes - You basically get all the performance /stability of the JVM which is pretty well proven in enterprise applications....*

Apart from all that, Clojure has some really impressive capabilities around concurrency. It's really worth watching this video: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey

Comment: "everything gets compiled to native code via JIT on the JVM" Totaly wrong... compiled in native code means we don't need something like a virtual machine. Here we need it.

Comment: It depends *why* you need native code. If all you care about is steady state performance then the JVM is absolutely up there with native code. If you need native libraries you can use JNI from the JVM (which is good enough for realtime 3D games). If however you need startup time in milliseconds or have severe memory constraints like on an embedded device then I agree the JVM may not be ideal.

Comment: mikera, you could also want ease of deployment (one less dependency for a Linux package, or not requiring the user to install the JRE on Windows, possibly even to give someone an .exe or elf). Yes, giving just a binary is a corner case, but still, it's possible with a native application but not with a program that needs the JVM.

Comment: @Alexander - agree that you want ease of deployment though depending on your perspective on dependencies this can still be a plus point for Clojure:  Clojure apps have exactly one direct dependency (the JVM) whereas a native binary has at least two (the operating system and the specific hardware architecture)

Comment: "everything gets compiled to native code via JIT on the JVM": NO. (clarify that and I remove my -1)

Comment: @haylem: Compiling down to native machine code is precisely what the JVM JIT compiler does. What kind of clarification do you think is needed?

Comment: @mikera: The "everything" bit.

Comment: @haylem: if you're referring to the fact that if code isn't run more than a few times then the JIT may not kick in then I agree. Have updated answer.

Comment: @mikera: yes. Also, some could say that the language itself has not pre-requisite on the existence of JIT. Other VMs may not support that. (removed my -1)

Answer (score 8):

**[Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)**

It appears to support all the above requirements. The link will take you to an online book that covers everything you need to know to get started.

Comment: The only thing is I really Hate brackets. Also I can't understand why they need brackets just everywhere ?

Comment: Common Lisp does generate native code?

Comment: @Klaim: Common Lisp is programming language. Programming Languages don't generate code, compilers do. So, just like for pretty much every other programming language on the planet (C, C++, Java, Ruby, ECMAScript, you name it), there are compilers for Common Lisp which generate native code. And just like for pretty much every other programming langage, there are compilers which generate JVML bytecode, CIL bytecode, C sourcecode, ECMAScript sourcecode. And just like for pretty much every other programming language, there are interpreters.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag> Thanks, I understand what you're saying, but in practice you think/create a language with choice of kind implementation, making easier to implement the language in an interpreted or native way depending on the language features. I'm asking about Lisp generating native code because, from what I heard of this language, it can process itself as it can evaluate strings and the program itself can be evaluated by itself. So, I'm surprised because of the native code generation (like in "thought for native code generation") might (or not?) prohibit such language. No?

Comment: @Klaim: Are you talking about the `eval` function? It's just a function, you can implement it any way you like. Some implementations have a separate interpreter which they ship with the compiled executable. Some just ship the compiler itself with the compiled executable. Some only compile the code at runtime anyway. And if you are talking about macros: *those* only execute at *compile time* anyway. That's the beauty of it.

Comment: @nCdy The ()s in Lisp come about as a result of providing syntax for differentiating between *lists* and *atoms* within an s-expression.

Comment: @Klaim: No worries. Trying to get programmers to understand that programming language semantics and programming language implementation strategies are completely orthogonal is one of my pet projects ;-) (Together with the orthogonality of performance and compilation, performance and static typing, static typing and strong typing, static typing and explicit typing, static typing and type safety.)

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: I'm beginning to suspect that you just like *saying* the word "orthogonal". ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: ;-) It *is* one of the most important concepts in programming, is it not? Probably the second most important after compositionality (and orthogonality is an important building block for achieving compositionality). And if you don't even understand it when you *encounter* it, how can you *implement* it in your own code?

Comment: So... But why lisp and not other ?

Comment: @nCdy Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Gary Rowe there is haskell / ocaml / erlang / python. why lisp ? )

Comment: @nCdy I can't really comment on the other languages, as I'm not sufficiently experienced in them. Personally, I think Lisp would provide what you're looking for, but others will have their own preferences. Perhaps give it a go and see how you get on.

Answer (score 5):

**OCaml** is the only language providing all the features you ask for. (But I don't know for mixin.) It even has a web framework named Ocsigen and it's more than a hype language, it's an old language, with a real user base (companies, universities, hobbyist) and years of improving and testing.

Comment: But metaprogramming is only done by a single-pass external tool (CamlP4).

Comment: Note that some of today's "hype language[s]" might become tomorrow's "old language[s], with real user base[s] [...] and years of improving and testing". They might even achieve the same level of market penetration and public acceptance. :)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely **Scala** can match your requirements:

1. compiled and runs on JVM so it is win/linux/mac.
2. supports both functional and OO programming.
3. it supports functional stuff you mention. Pattern matching looks great and actively used. It lacks tail recursion support as JVM doesn't support it but recursion calls can be optimized in some cases.
4. metaprogramming is **not** supported. The language is great^W **quite good** for DSL. (fixed)
5. it has mixins (traits).
6. have a look at Lift web framework. It uses functional features of the language and has advanced features so very interesting to look at. There are also some other web frameworks (play!, etc.)
7. based on JVM so stable.
8. Syntax is quite clean. There is no parenthesis hell (sorry lispers, that's just my personal opinion) over there and the use of semicolons is reduced to optional in many cases.

Moreover Scala has great support for parallel programming (by Actors). Scala community is growing and it is used in real projects (Twitter). The language is quite difficult to learn as has a lot of features and syntactic sugar but once you handle it you certainly will enjoy programming with it.

Comment: When compared to clojure Scala's trait allow mixin composistion in which trait (interface) can inherit classes via [type-linearisation](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/08/scala-class-linearization.html).

Comment: 4. Metaprogramming *is not*  supported at all. DSLs are implemented in high order functions and overloading, without any help of metaprogramming. As a result - those DSLs are limited, limiting and slow. No compile-time code generation is available in Scala. Nothing like Lisp macros.

Comment: I really dislike Scala syntax after all... It's personal )

Comment: @SK-logic I checked it and now I agree with you. Once I looked through "DSL in Action" and there was Scala DSL example so I thought it is OK for DSL. Obviously Lisp, Clojure will work much better here.